# How to split a column by the second upper character in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I got a table in SQL Server with the one column like this.

| Textcolumn |
| --- |
| SzhH |
| Tma |
| SzhH |
| CcMtp |
| XYZ |

I want to split the `Textcolumn` into 2 columns like this (with the delimiter is the uppercase character)

| Textcolumn | leftcol | rightcol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SzhH | Szh | H |
| Tma | Tma | Null |
| SzhH | Szh | H |
| CcMtp | Cc | Mtp |
| XYZ | XYZ | Null |

I have tried this. But it did not work. Please help me!

```
WITH unique_text AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        LOWER(SUBSTRING([TextColumn], 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING([TextColumn], 2, LEN([TextColumn])) AS LoweredText
    FROM 
        sc_join_group
)
SELECT 
    *,
    SUBSTRING(LoweredText, 1, PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', LoweredText) - 1) AS leftcol,
    SUBSTRING(LoweredText, PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', LoweredText), LEN(LoweredText)) AS rightright
FROM
    unique_text;
```

Comment: Are you really still using SQL Server 2008? That version ran *completely* out of support over **4 years ago**.

Comment: @ThomA No, I am not. Thank you for asking

Comment: So what version *are* you using? And what are you *actually* trying to do? A one-off split? A frequently used query? SQL in general and T-SQL in particular are very weak in text processing. SQL is a query language, not a text manipulation language. T-SQL has no regular expressions. It's *far* easier to split the text in a client language like C# or Python

Comment: For frequent queries, it's better to split the data upon insertion. For one-off conversions, it's easier to write a script in C# or Python and use regular expressions to split the data then save it. You can also use SQL Server's support for Python scripts through `sp_execute_external_script` to split the data and return it as a result set.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18. Thank you for the suggestion. I am going to try it out

Comment: That's your client tool, not the SQL Server version. You can use SSMS to connect to multiple SQL Server versions. It's not even part of the SQL Server install, it's a separately downloaded tool

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've checked it. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU20)

Comment: As for why your query fails, it's because most SQL Server installations use case-*in*sensitive collations. `A` matches both `a` and `A`. You can specify a case-sensitive collation with the `COLLATION` clause, eg `COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS`. The collation specifies the sort order *and* the comparison rules used when searching.

Comment: If your upper case character denotes a delimiter then why would `SzhH` not also be `S, zhH` or `S, zh, H`

Comment: What does the *real* data look like? If it's Title- or Camel-cased phrases, a C# library like Humanizer could split it into words. There are equivalents in Python too

Comment: @Stu The delimiter is the SECOND uppercase. sorry I did not specify it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah, using Python would be easy. My customer want to have it done in SQL server =((

Comment: FYI@PanagiotisKanavos when I use COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, it get the error "Expression type bigint is invalid for COLLATE clause."

Comment: The error is telling you what is wrong ...

Comment: Why are you trying to `COLLATE` a `bigint` column/expression..? `COLLATE`ing a numerical data type doesn't make sense; they don't contain alpha characters nor do they sort like an alpha (`2` is less than `10`, rather than greater).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative version you can try, making use of *translate* on a case-sensitive collation to identify the character to split on:

```
select Textcolumn, 
  IsNull(Left(TextColumn, p - 1), Textcolumn) Leftcol, 
  Right(TextColumn, Len(TextColumn) - p + 1) rightcol
from t
cross apply(values(Translate(Textcolumn collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', Replicate('*',26))))n(t)
cross apply(values(NullIf(Iif(Replace(n.t,'*','') = '', 0, CharIndex('*', n.t, 2)), 0)))p(p)
```

See this [demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MXxv4LQS)

Comment: You have come to my rescue. It works like a charm. Thank you very much